# Sed/Awk Removing Multiple Lines From Yaml Until Two Spaces

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

This one is stumping me and I can't seem to find an exact match from other SO questions. I've gotten pretty close so maybe someone can point out something I'm missing.

I have a yaml file named test.yml that looks like:

```
sites:
  qwerty:
    hosts:
      - qwerty.test
  abc:
    repo:
    hosts:
      - abc.test
    other:
  xyz:
    repo:
    hosts:
      - xyz.test
utilities:
  stuff:
    - thing
    - thing 2
```

I want to remove all of the abc: block using a bash script. I can't count on the number of lines being the same. I'm open to using any method as long as it's widely acceptable (this is for an open source project). Ideally it would look like this when finished:

```
sites:
  qwerty:
    hosts:
      - qwerty.test
  xyz:
    repo:
    hosts:
      - xyz.test
utilities:
  stuff:
    - thing
    - thing 2
```

Right now I've got to this:

```
sed -e "/  abc:/,/  \w/d" test.yml > test.tmp
```

But this results in:

```
sites:
  qwerty:
    hosts:
      - qwerty.test
```

My thought process was to match until there were two spaces and a word but I seem to be matching two spaces when there are four and that deletes everything. How can I target two spaces and a word explicitly using Regex? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The "better way to do this" would be to use tools that support the data format natively. Would you be open to using jq, with [y2j](https://github.com/wildducktheories/y2j) as an interface?

Comment: It's a possibility... but not ideal. I don't want to add a dependency if I don't need to. On top of that, this script is going to be part of it's own interface so I'd need to find a way to call it in the background. But thank you for pointing to that. I'll investigate it as a last resort.

Comment: @MichaelHeath Your title is vague. For instance what do you mean by `until two spaces`?

Comment: It's hard to see in the example file that I made above. But my general idea was to use sed to regex match till there was two spaces and a word. So first I would match the site I'm looking for (in this example abc) and then it would match and delete until the next site which has two spaces and a word (xyz in this example). Does that help/make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work according to your input data.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ print_flag=1 } 
{
    if( $0 ~ /  abc:/ ) 
    {
       print_flag=0;
       next
    } 
    if( $0 ~ /^  [a-zA-Z0-9]+:$/ ) 
    {
        print_flag=1;   
    } 
    if ( print_flag == 1 ) 
        print $0

} ' input.txt
```

### Output:

```
sites:
  qwerty:
    hosts:
      - qwerty.test
  xyz:
    repo:
    hosts:
      - xyz.test
utilities:
  stuff:
    - thing
    - thing 2
```

Regards!

Comment: This is extremely close to what I'm looking for. The only thing that would make this perfect is making abc variable (so I can delete the xyz block for example). I'm going to work on this for a bit...

Comment: I've been able to get this to work by utilizing an awk variable and removing the regex forward slashes. The only thing is that when you target xyz it remove the utilities block.

Comment: Just edited your answer with the last 1% that made it work for me. Thanks @Matias Barrios. I didn't know you could put that type of logic in awk. :)

Comment: @michaelheath Sorry my delay in replying. I have been away from my pc until now. Glad to see you were able to modify this to fit it to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;/^\s*abc:/!b;:b;$d;N;/^(\s*)abc.*\n\1[^\n]*$/{/^(\s*)abc.*\n\1\S/!bb};s/.*\n//;ba' file
```

If it does not begin with `abc` we are not interested. If it does and it is the last line, delete it. Otherwise, append the next line and check if the indent is the same. If it is not, append another line and check again (if at any time it is the last line, delete all lines collected so far). If the appended line is indented the same as the first i.e. the line beginning `abc`, delete all lines but the last and then repeat from the first command.

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate  `json` and `yaml` files, you should use tools native to data format.
You can use [[ y2j ]](https://github.com/wildducktheories/y2j) as pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48233103/sed-awk-removing-multiple-lines-from-yaml-until-two-spaces/48233361#comment83448790_48233103). Download the zip from the git repo and extract it to folder. Place your yaml file inside the before mentioned folder and do :

```
# cat test.yaml 
sites:
  qwerty:
    hosts:
      - qwerty.test
  abc:
    repo:
    hosts:
      - abc.test
    other:
  xyz:
    repo:
    hosts:
      - xyz.test
utilities:
  stuff:
    - thing
    - thing 2
# ./y2j 'del(.[].abc)' <test.yaml | ./j2y
sites:
  qwerty:
    hosts:
    - qwerty.test
  xyz:
    hosts:
    - xyz.test
    repo: null
utilities:
  stuff:
  - thing
  - thing 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple but not particularly flexible awk solution might be this:

```
awk -v tag="abc:" '/^  [^ ]/ {n=0} /^  [^ ]/ && $1==tag {n=1} (1-n)' input.yaml
```

Broken out for easier reading:

- `-v tag="abc:"` - this sets a variable that'll be stripped from your input.
- `/^  [^ ]/ {n=0}` - If we find ourselves on a line indented with two spaces, start printing.
- `/^  [^ ]/ && $1==tag {n=1}` - But if the first word on the line is the tag we specified above, *stop* printing.
- `(n-1)` - Print the line if n=0.

You could alternately reverse the meaning of `n`, like this:

```
awk -v n=1 -v tag="abc:" '/^  [^ ]/{n=1} /^  [^ ]/ && $1==tag {n=0} n' input.yaml
```

Note that with this usage, we need to "prime" the `n` variable so that lines before the first instance of `/^  [^ ]/` will be printed.

This is NOT a yaml parser, it's a text pattern parser. You could easily provide perfectly valid yaml to it that was formatted differently and would therefore be parsed incorrectly.

It seems theoretically possible to me to do very limited parsing of actual yaml within awk. You'd be missing a lot of data types, but you could write something that would be more flexible than the solution above. But managing a complex set of awk functions seems like quite a bit more work than adding a couple of tools like `jq` and `y2j` to your toolbox. If you're manipulating files in yaml, I would submit that you want native support for yaml, not hacks like this.